# Lumen 5.6 htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, lumen

WordPress has been installed on the root of the production server and my Lumen framework is in public_html/developer/api folder but when we try to access api folder through url it is showing WordPress 404 page not found error. One htaccess file has put in api (Lumen) folder and another in /developer/api/public.

htaccess file code inside api folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /developer/api/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|quotes|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /developer/api/public/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and inside api/public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: hi, has your issue already been resolved?